# How to create a session that is an array in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, session

I want to fill session with many ids.
How to create a session with many contents like an array?

example :

```
session[:store_id] = []
session[:store_id] << store.id
```

I get a result like this if I add many ids to my session :

```
 session[:store_id] << 1
 =>   result : [1]
 session[:store_id] << 2
 =>   result : [2]
```

I expect a result like this :

```
session[:store_id] = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Try with `session[:store_id] ||= []`

Comment: can i put that as answer so you can vote or accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `session[:store_id] ||= []`